# What is the double multiplication sign for?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

I accidentally typed `4 ** 5` into Google and received `1,024` instead of `20`. But `4^5` is also `1024`...

Does the double multiplication sign also mean the power sign? Why two symbols?

Comment: That's Fortran syntax.

Comment: An idea for different syntax: ^ can be hard to type with some keyboard layouts. With German (or ...) layout, for example, the key for it lies above the TAB key. Additionally, n^a will be put as nâ; you have to hit the awkwardly placed key twice to get ^ out. * is situated better. Ruby uses **, too.

Comment: For people who use Google as a calculator, [this](http://www.googleguide.com/help/calculator.html) is helpful. (There was once a complete listing in the help files on Google, but it seems to have disappeared.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exponentiation in some software. So a**b means a^b.

Answer (score 7):

Caveat: The symbol ^ in C family languages is bitwise xor.  This is true in Python, too.  The ** symbol is also seen in Python.